# Create legend entry for each line plot coming from one column of matrix

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib, matrix, plot

I plot my matrix `nH.T` which has 4 columns. So I want to make the legend, each column has the name from list `latent_prot2`.

```
latent_prot2 = np.array(["A","B","C","E"])

ax3 = plt.subplot2grid((3, 4), (2, 0), colspan=3, rowspan=1)
ax3.plot(nH.T, label=[n for i,n in enumerate(latent_prot2)])
plt.legend()
```

What I get is all the list printed out for each line.

[image]

I tried `ax3.plot(nH.T, label=[n[i] for i,n in enumerate(latent_prot2)])` or change the last line to `plt.legend(label=latent_prot2)` but they are not work. How to write the name for each column data from matrix in legend from list?
And it would be good if I don't have to go via for loop but I don't know that is possible or not.

Comment: Oh thanks. I transposed it, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the `label` argument to `plot` you will get the same label for each plotted curve.

To manipulate the legend, you would pass the list of elements to the `legend` call

```
ax.legend(labels=["A","B","C","E"])
```

Complete example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

a = np.cumsum(np.cumsum(np.random.randn(15,4), axis=0), axis=1)

lab = np.array(["A","B","C","E"])

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(a)
ax.legend(labels=lab )

plt.show()
```

[image]